# Multiple form in a single asp file

Tags: html, forms, asp-classic

I'd like to use a couple of `HTML forms` control in a single `Classic ASP` file ? Can I use couple of forms in a single `Classic ASP` and is that a good design pattern ?

```
<form action="../action1.asp">
</form>
<form action="../action2.asp">
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use multiple forms in one Classic ASP page. You'll need to be aware each form will only submit it's own set of form fields. I would recommend using unique variable names within each form (including any buttons) and give each form it's own unique name and id. Also be clear on whether you are using POST or GET to transmit the information within the forms.

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="../action1.asp">
</form>

<form id="form2" name="form2" method="post" action="../action2.asp">
</form>
```